# My app crashes with setOnCameraIdleListener

Tags: android, google-maps

I am new to android and I am writing google map cluster. 
The following code is used to get coordinate after swiping the map.

```
googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraIdle() {
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = googleMap.getCameraPosition();
        mobileLocation.updateLocation(cameraPosition.target.latitude, cameraPosition.target.longitude);
    }
});
```

But it is crashed with the `googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(mClusterManager);`
 in google map cluster.

Can someone please give me any suggestion?

Comment: What's the crash log?

Comment: write your crash log.

Comment: if I write the googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(mClusterManger); I can't get the coordinate after i swap the map. But if i commented out the code, the marker clustering is not working. what should I do?